# How to make a picture link with HTML?

Tags: html, hyperlink, image

I have made a picture link with this code snip:

```
<a href='feed.php'><img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Icons\Feed.png"/></a>
```

But no picture appears on my page, why?

(I'm currently only using my page locally!)

Comment: do you plan to deploy this site online ?  if yes, use a relative path already.  If not, when you go live... all your pictures will be in error and you will have to change all the path to the good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you (are trying to) use a local file reference.

Either use the relative path

or

```
<a href='feed.php'><img src="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Project/Icons/Feed.png"/></a>
```

Please be aware that if you plan to use this 'online' it will fail because of the LOCAL reference.

If you load the page through your webserver you should use:

```
<a href='feed.php'><img src="/Icons/Feed.png"/></a>
```

Or

```
<a href='feed.php'><img src="http://yoursite.local/Icons/Feed.png"/></a>
```

Or whatever the path to the image is.

I would prefer the relative path (the first) though which enables you to move your page to another domain without your links / images breaking.

Comment: Removed the downvote, it was meant for a different answer. That said, since OP is linking to a local (relative) PHP file, its almost certainly a remote page and therefore the `file://` protocol would be forbidden.

Comment: I copied your snip and replaced my old one with it, but the picture still won't show up?

Comment: @NorS: If you load the page through your webserver you should cannot use local `file:///` reference. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't link local files from a remote web page. This is to prevent webpages from accessing files on the end-user's computer.

Change this: `C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\Icons\Feed.png`

To this: `http://yourwebsitehere.com/Project/Icons/Feed.png`

EDIT: Since you say its only used locally, then you need to use this instead:
`file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Project/Icons/Feed.png`

Also, make sure the image is actually located where you think it is!

Try typing `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Project/Icons/Feed.png` into your browser's address bar and see what happens.

Comment: My browser showed the picture! But it still won't be displayed at my page, even though I followed your advice?

Comment: Relative path should be used.  if you put http://yourwebsite.... everywhere, if you change host to http://mywebsite... you will have to change everything.  you should only use ../img/myImgage.jpg