# Html links (i can't see the pictures)

Tags: html

Is there a something wrong with this code? I save it like that but I can't see the pictures in the page.

```
<li><a href="pinformation.html"
title="P information">Praktisch</a></li>
```

Comment: Post some css, assuming you are using `background-image`. Because i dont see `<img>` elements

Comment: actually i copied everything from main.html file. then i changed header and content. that's it.

Answer (score 2):

There are no `<img>` elements (i.e. pictures) in the markup you've provided, so none should show.

Answer (score 0):

You want a hyperlink on a picture I presume? I think it's this:

```
<a href="link"> <img src="c:/image.png" alt="text" width="42" height="42"></a>
```

You should provide more detail.

[How to make a picture link with HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180633/how-to-make-a-picture-link-with-html?rq=1)

Comment: nope i dont wanna a hyperlink on a picture but on a text. i said that i can't see the pictures at the website. As i said before i copied everything from main.html file and changed only the header and content.

Comment: I could only presume that due to lack of detail in your question. Perhaps with more detail you will get somewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask